# How to configure KCL worker properties for Amazon KCL client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-kcl

We have a java based KCL worker consuming records from DynamoDB streams. I want to understand based on high number of partition in table and shards in streams, what values should be given while creating worker. Also these tables are actively merging and splitting shards.
Asking about following properties (with default values) -

###### failoverTimeMillis = 10000

###### shardSyncIntervalMillis = 60000

Comment: Tables never merge partitions. Stream shards roll-over every 4 hours.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But is there any mathematical explanation to explain how long a lease should be or how often sync should happen based on high number of active shards. I don't think on high scale I should rely on default configuration. I can already see limit_exceed_exception when shards are synced due to calling describe_stream internally.